# TPM 2.0: Avoiding key (re-)generation overhead on every use

Tags: tpm

I'm developing an application that needs to generate an RSA key in the TPM to be used for sign operations. The public part is registered towards a backend once, and the private part is then be used repeatedly for authentication. This use will be across machine shutdown/restart cycles. At the root of my hierarchy I have an SRK-key (i.e. based on such template) generated using CreatePrimary(). I know I can regenerate this key for subsequent sessions (by saving the random input in the program's data). The program's actual signing key can also be saved in encrypted form and then loaded using the Load function once the SRK-key has been regenerated.

So functionally everything works, but I would like to avoid the key regeneration overhead. What are my options here?

1) As far as I can read (but please correct if I'm wrong) a ContextSave will not survive a power cycle (documentation says it resets across Power Reset). Please confirm if ContextSave can be used or not.

2) there's a function called EvictControl which does the job. But it involves NV memory which is limited (so if an application "forgets" such a returned handle, the memory can never be released, without resetting the whole TPM) and will wear the TPM (only on initial enrollment). Is this suitable?

3) Perhaps there's a third option I haven't found? Is there a "default" SRK that can be used so I don't have to (re-)generate one for instance?

If nothing else works I plan to use this function but I was wondering if there's a different option. I don't understand why there's not an ExportPrimary()/ImportPrimary() or such that could export a primary that could be imported later, without touching NV storage. The export would be done under a key stored inside the TPM in NV storage (only regenerated on TPM clear etc) and thereby have same security level as EvictControl but without taking up NV-storage per generated key.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the question, it seems like you are re-generating the SRK on each power-up. You are really not supposed to do that, the SRK is supposed to be a persistent key, see https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG-TPM-v2.0-Provisioning-Guidance-Published-v1r1.pdf.

As to how to make it persistent, it seems like you already know how to do that, just use EvictControl.

Comment: There's both the concept of Shared and Dedicated SRK's. Use of a shared SRK is not without problems in my use case (since the device either may or may not be provisioned beforehand so I can't know if there's one written to NV and I would rather not write it myself). So Dedicated SRK is the only option, but this is where it seems one cannot persist the SRK outside the TPM (even though this would be technically possible) but only on TPM itself, in NV. In my opinion, the shared SRK in the spec should have been mandatory (also cleared on TPM clear).

Comment: Sounds like you have a bit of a process problem... If you must deal with both provisioned and unprovisioned TPMs the number and complexity of use cases to cover will grow quickly. Good luck!

Comment: OK maybe a dumb question: But can I in practice assume (i.e. on a Windows PC with TPM 2.0) that there is an SRK there already? I was unsure if the provisioning was done when e.g. enabling Bitlocker, or if the SRK is always there as soon as the TPM is switched on (without the user doing anything)?

Comment: Well, if you clear the TPM the SRK will not be there. To create a dedicated SRK you will need the hierarchy auth, so some level of provisioning must be done... I don't know what BitLocker does exactly, but I'm assuming it does some minimal provisioning on an unprovisioned chip, like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/trustedplatformmodule/enable-tpmautoprovisioning?view=win10-ps